# Why is wordpress permalink path wrong for single blog posts?

Tags: permalinks

I'm developing my site with MAMP and my homepage is at localhost:8888/wordpress

When I click on the link to my blog page (home.php) the url looks like this: localhost:8888/wordpress/blog

All good so far.

However, when I click on a blog post from the home.php template the url looks like this:

localhost:8888/wordpress/blogpostname

How can I make it so  it's localhost:8888/wordpress/blog/blogpostname ?

When I changed my permalink settings to localhost:8888/wordpress/%category%/%postname%/
it still left out the /blog in the URL.

Why is it doing that and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should try changing the post permalink to - /blog/%category%/%postname%/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `/blog/` in your permalink settings:

```
/blog/%category%/%postname%/
```

or

```
/blog/%postname%/
```

Comment: That works but it adds the blog prefix to custom post types as well.

Comment: that's what the `'with_front'` parameter is for when you [register your custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters), set that to `false`.